# Need to resolve issue related to orientation in MonoTouch

Tags: ios6, xamarin.ios, c#-3.0, ios-simulator

i want to fetch the current orientation of device. I have written this code in AppDelegate class :
my code:

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft == (UIInterfaceOrientation)UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Orientation &&
            UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight == (UIInterfaceOrientation)UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Orientation) {
            //code
        } else {
            //code
        }
```

**UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Orientation is giving unknown?**

Comment: Note that your condition above will always be false since the `Orientation` cannot be **simultaneously** `LandscapeLeft` and `LandscapeRight`. Beside that more information would be helpful to understand your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the `InterfaceOrientation` property of your `UIViewController`?

That is probably a better value to check against, as it is the state in which your app is currently rotated and "allowed" to rotate to.  Checking the `UIDevice` might not match the rotation of your UI.